# NOT a maximal ideal of the ring of Gaussian integers

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals, gaussian-integers

I have to show that $I= \{  a+bi : a,b \in \mathbb{Z} , a=5m , b=5n\}$ is NOT a maximal ideal of $\mathbb Z[i]$.

For this if I take $J= \{  a+bi : 5\ $divides $ a^2+b^2 \}$ then , I can have that $4+3i \in J$ but  NOT in $I$, and $1+5i \in \mathbb  Z[i]$ but NOT in $J$. Then $ I \subset J\subset \mathbb Z[i]$. But the problem lies in showing J as a subring:

for $x, y\in J$, say $ x = a+ib$ and $y = c+id$, $x-y = (a-c)+i(b-d)$. Then $5$ must divide $(a-c)^2 + (b-d)^2$. Now 5 divides $a^2+b^2$ and $c^2+d^2$, but how do I know that 5 divides $2(ac-bd)$ ?

Edited to add another related query:  For an earlier problem of similar nature, where ideal I = $\{a+ib:$ a and b are multiples of 2} , J was assumed to be $\{a+ib:$ 2 divides  $\ a^2+b^2$}. I understand that here that  $\ a^2+b^2$=$(a+ib)(a−ib)$. Is there any similar structure to get **non maximal ideals** of Z[i]?

Any help would be duly acknowledged.

Comment: It is not an ideal, since $4 + 3 \sqrt {-1} - (3 + 4 \sqrt {-1}) = 1 - \sqrt {-1}$ has norm $1^2 + 1^2 = 2$ not divisible by $5$.

Comment: Could you please advise a feasible ideal $J$ for which I could get a relevant $I$?

Comment: Try compute $Z[\sqft {-1}] / I$ and explain this is not a field.

Comment: As the answer explained, $J = (2 + \sqrt {-1})$ works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The non-trivial ideal $(2+i)\mathbb Z[i]$ contains $I=5\mathbb Z[i]$, owing to the factorisation $5=(2+i)(2-i)$. This settles the matter.

Comment: Does that mean $(2-i)Z[i]$ can also be such an ideal?

Comment: @SharmiC yes, that is the conjugate ideal.

Comment: I have another question. For an earlier problem of similar nature, where ideal $I$ was given as {a+ib: where a and b were multiples of 2}, $J$ was assumed to be {a+ib: 2 divides $\ a^2 +b^2$}. i understood that here that $\ a^2 + b^2 = (a+ib)(a-ib)$. Is there any similar structure to get non maximal ideals of Z[i]?

Comment: @SharmiC Ask another question.